# How to display multiple error messages on form submit?

Tags: angular, validation, form-submit

Hi I am developing web application in Angular. I am trying to display error messages on submitting form. I have two drop-down lists. I am trying to display error messages if the user does not select any options from drop-down list. If the user does not select option from first drop-down list then I am able to display error message but I am not able to display error message for second drop-down list.

```
<form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="permissionEditorForm" #f="ngForm" novalidate
      (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid ? savePermission(selectedUserRole.value,selectedScopeName.value) :(!userrole.valid && showErrorAlert('User role is required', 'Please select user role'));">

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="userrole">User Role:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10" ng-class="{'valid':userrole.$valid}">
            <select #selectedUserRole autofocus name='userrole' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='userrole' required>
                <option value="">Select User Role</option>
                <option *ngFor="let userrole of userroles; let i = index" [value]="userrole.userroleid">
                    {{userrole.username}}
                </option>
            </select>
            <span *ngIf="(f.submitted && !userrole.valid && !userrole) || (!userrole.valid && userrole.dirty)" class="errorMessage">
                User Role Required!
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="scopename">Scope Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10" ng-class="{'valid':scopename.$valid}">
            <select #selectedScopeName autofocus name='scopename' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='scopename' required>
                <option value="">Select Scope Name</option>
                <option *ngFor="let scope of scopes; let i=index" [value]="scope.scopeid">
                    {{scope.scopevalue}}
                </option>
            </select>
            <span *ngIf="(f.submitted && !scopename.valid && !scopename) || (!scopename.valid && scopename.dirty)" class="errorMessage">
                Scope Name Required!
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label class="control-label col-md-2"> </label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="checkbox">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr class="edit-last-separator-hr" />
    </div>


    <div class="form-group actionBtn-form-group">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Permission"/>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

I have written below condition to make validation.

```
<form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="permissionEditorForm" #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid ?savePermission(selectedUserRole.value,selectedScopeName.value) :
(!userrole.valid && showErrorAlert('User role is required', 'Please select user role'));">
```

Above piece of code validates only first drop-down list.

I have if condition on submit button. I am able to display error message for the first drop-down list. can someone help me to make above validation works? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What you're using is Angular not AngularJS, they're different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the model of your form (i.e. the fields containing the **values** entered/selected in your form), with the internal structure of FormGroups and FormControls used by the form.

The former just contains values (user role ids, scope IDs). There is no `valid` or `dirty` fields on those values. They're just strings or numbers. Those are the fields passed as input to the ngModel directive:

```
[(ngModel)]='userrole'
[(ngModel)]='scopename'
```

The latter is the one allowing to test if form controls are valid, dirty, etc. Those are stored in local template variables (**that should have different name**) initialized with the ngModel directive instance:

```
#roleCtrl="ngModel"
#scopeCtrl="ngModel"
```

You're also using the same variable `userrole` for two different things: once as the model of your first select box:

```
[(ngModel)]='userrole'
```

and once as the variable referring to the current role in the loop:

```
*ngFor="let userrole of userroles;
```

This is really not a good idea.

You should start by having a model object in your component, and to bind the form controls to fields of this model:

```
model = {
  roleId: '',
  scopeId: ''
};
```

Then what is done on submission should be part of the component, not of the view. And the component has access to the model of the form, so there is no need to pass it from the view.

Your form should look like this:

```
<form *ngIf="formResetToggle" class="form-horizontal" name="permissionEditorForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="savePermission(f)">

    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="userrole">User Role:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10" ng-class="{'valid': roleCtrl.valid}">
            <select #roleCtrl="ngModel" autofocus name='userrole' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='model.roleId' required>
                <option value="">Select User Role</option>
                <option *ngFor="let userrole of userroles; let i = index" [value]="userrole.userroleid">
                    {{userrole.username}}
                </option>
            </select>
            <span *ngIf="(!roleCtrl.valid && (f.submitted || roleCtrl.dirty)" class="errorMessage">
                User Role Required!
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="scopename">Scope Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10" ng-class="{'valid': scopeCtrl.valid}">
            <select #selectedScopeName autofocus name='scopename' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='model.scopeId' required>
                <option value="">Select Scope Name</option>
                <option *ngFor="let scope of scopes; let i=index" [value]="scope.scopeid">
                    {{scope.scopevalue}}
                </option>
            </select>
            <span *ngIf="(!scopeCtrl.valid && (f.submitted || scopeCtrl.dirty)" class="errorMessage">
                Scope Name Required!
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...
```